# Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.CoreWebView2 Blowups randomly

Tags: c#, webview2

I am using it (as a web crawler --- which allows me to also walk and execute forms).

In debug, often when I hit a breakpoint that is not using it(in C#), the application dies with no error messages. etc. despite lots of handlers to try to identify the issue.

In Release, it happens a lot less -- with 500,000 navigations not causing an issue.

VS 2022 being used

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should attach [DebugDiag](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=58210) to the release process and capture a dump on 2nd chance exceptions to examine the callstack for the exception that shuts down the process.